# line 21 show ; expected

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors

The first line contains a single integer p denoting the length of array.  The second line contains space-separated integers describing each respective element in array. The third line prints an integer indicating the number of negative arrays.

```
package asgn3;

import java.util.*;

public class Asgn3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0, result = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the array ");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        int j = 0;
        String[] s1 = s.split(" ");
        int a[] = new int[s1.length];

        for(String s2:s1) {
            a[j] = Integer.parseInt(s2));
            j++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for ( j = i; j < a.length; j ++) {
                for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                    result += a[k];
                }

                if(result < 0)
                    count ++;
            }
            System.out.println("no. of negatve arrays is "+count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issues is usage of extra unnecessary parenthesis. Change,

```
a[j]=Integer.parseInt(s2));
```

with

```
a[j]=Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra bracket **)** from end of line

```
a[j] = Integer.parseInt(s2);
```